# The name of a group in relation to a champion/representative

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a noun for a group of people in relation to an entity that serves as the group's hero, representative, champion, or defender. The important bit is that it could be the case that this role might only exist in the mind(s) of the defender itself, kind of like Don Quixote. I can name some examples to illustrate:

- Batman -> Gotham
- Bolivar -> South America
- Harriet Tubman -> Abolitionism
- Huey Long -> Louisiana
- Communist Party -> Proletariat
- Hitler -> Germany

Is there such a word?

Comment: Please read the description of the tag that you chose. I provided an answer below, but I believe that [the SWR tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) would be more appropriate for this question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that any word exists with such a broad meaning. For some more specific meanings, you could try:

- "[constituents](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/constituent)" / "[constituency](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/constituency)" (this could apply to the people of Louisiana represented by Long or the people of Germany represented by Hitler)
- "[protectees](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/protectee)" / "[protectorate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/protectorate)" (I suppose that this might apply to Gothamites defended by Batman, but it is usually restricted to even more specific meanings)
- "[clients](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/client)" / "[clientele](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clientele)" (this likely wouldn't apply to any of your examples, as it usually refers to countries protected by other countries)
- "[cause](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cause)" (this could apply to abolitionism championed by Harriet Tubman or to the proletariat championed by various communist parties)

Comment: constituency is probably most accurate, unfortunately it is polluted by electoral connotations. clientele is close, but it presumes a two way street that was not necessarily there in the case of a quixotic type champion. And I like the territoriality of "protectorate"

Answer (score 0):

You could call such a person that group's **messiah.** [The Free Dictionary defines it as:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Messiah)

> One who is anticipated as, regarded as, or professes to be a savior or liberator.

While the word is typically positive, it can (as the above definition suggests) be used to describe someone who merely *professes* to be a savior, not just someone who actually *is* one.

Comment: I believe the relationship the question asks for is actually in the opposite direction. OP asks for a word for the group which has a messiah.

Comment: "Antiochans" might work, probably too esoteric though. I'm writing for a broad audience.

Answer (score 0):

The people might be, or at least be seen as, *dependents*. While the word often refers to financial dependency, it can have a broader meaning, as in the example cited on Cambridge dictionary "Indeed, carers have the duty not only not to harm their dependents themselves but to protect them from being harmed by others." See https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dependant

Comment: tribe might work.